# How to select last record by two parameters?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with log 'snmp trap cisco port':

```
mysql> select id, ip, `index`, trap_date from cisco_trap  order by id desc limit 20;

 id     ip          index  trap_date           
 61110  1582065982      6  2017-03-06 10:27:07 
 61109  1582065982      6  2017-03-06 10:21:58 
 61108   175141121     45  2017-03-05 22:40:58 
 61107   175141121     45  2017-03-05 22:40:52 
 61106   175141121     45  2017-03-05 22:39:21 
 61105   175141121     45  2017-03-05 22:20:18 
 61104   175141121     45  2017-03-05 22:17:56 
 61103   175141121     45  2017-03-05 22:17:50 
 61102  1582065982     16  2017-03-03 17:00:33 
 61101  1582065982      6  2017-03-03 17:00:36 
 61100  1582065982      6  2017-03-03 16:42:47 
 61099  1582065982     16  2017-03-03 15:29:55 
 61098  1582065982      6  2017-03-03 15:30:03 
 61097  1582065982     16  2017-03-03 15:27:28 
 61096  1582065982      6  2017-03-03 15:27:23 
 61095  1582065982      6  2017-03-03 15:26:27 
 61094  1582065982     16  2017-03-03 15:26:21 
 61093  1582065982     16  2017-03-03 15:25:58 
 61092  1582065982      6  2017-03-03 15:25:52 
 61091  1582065982      6  2017-03-03 15:23:51
```

ip is ip in inet_ntoa and `index` is number of cisco port.
How to select last record(log) by each port(`index`) each ip?

Comment: Check out GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `MAX` with `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT * from cisco_trap 
JOIN (
  select ip, `index`, max(trap_date) as max_date 
  from cisco_trap
  group by ip, `index`
) t
ON t.ip = cisco_trap.ip 
AND t.`index` = cisco_trap.`index`
AND t.max_date = cisco_trap.trap_date
```

Comment: The query runs very slowly (

Comment: @Vadym query speed will depend on number of records in the database table. If you can add a `WHERE` clause and restrict the query on a specific duration of `trap_date` that may help in speeding up the query.

Answer (score 0):

There are two method for getting this done:

1. This gives 100% accurate result. but can slow.

   ```
   SELECT id, 
       ip, 
      `index`, 
      trap_date 
   FROM cisco_trap 
   WHERE id IN ( 
              SELECT max(id) 
              FROM cisco_trap  
              GROUP BY ip, index 
            ) 
   ORDER BY id DESC 
   LIMIT 20
   ```

2 As i have research 100 of time. people said to used this, because it is faster then above query, but in my case this query doesn't give accurate result. so try 1

```
SELECT id, ip, `index`, trap_date 
FROM ( 
       SELECT * 
       FROM cisco_trap 
       ORDER BY id DESC , 
                index DESC, 
                id DESC
     ) 
GROUP BY ip , index 
limit 20;
```